# Add a tag when the user presses the space key

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tags input text field that needs to listen when the user types a bunch of characters followed by a space, my JavaScript file has a function that I have subscribed to from my HTML markup for the input text field. When the user hits space then the word typed needs to styled, so that the text becomes white and the background "#**007bff**" and appended to my input text field as a child. I have tried using this function but the Console throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleKeyUp is not defined at Queries 61:146

This is the markup for the input text field:

```
<input type ="text" class="Form-control" id="tags" onkeyup="handleKeyUp" >
```

This is the JavaScript code that should detect space keyboard events and add the tags to the input text field.

```
let tagInputs = document.getElementById("tags");
// Function to listen for space and add tags
function handleKeyUp(evt) {
  if(evt.key === ' ') {
    // Get the text typed before space
    let text = evt.target.value;
    // Create a new span for styling the tag
    let ftext = document.createElement('span');
    // Style the tag element
    ftext.style.backgroundColor = "#007BFF";
    ftext.style.color = "#FFF";
    // Append a space before the tag
    tagInputs.value += ' ';
    // Append the tag to the input field
    tagInputs.appendChild(ftext);
   }
}
```

Comment: How about `onkeyup="handleKeyUp(e)"`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues in this code.

1. `document.getElemetById("tags");`: You can see there is a spelling mistake.
2. `onkeyup="handleKeyUp"`: It should be `onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event)"`
3. Put your *if* condition like this: `if (evt.key == " " || evt.code == "Space" || evt.keyCode == 32)`

You can refer to the below code:

```js
function handleKeyUp(evt) {
    let tagInputs = document.getElementById("tags");
    console.log(evt);
    if (evt.key == " " || evt.code == "Space" || evt.keyCode == 32) {
        // Create a new span for styling the tag
        let ftext = document.createElement('span');
        // Style the tag element
        ftext.style.backgroundColor="#007BFF";
        ftext.style.color = "#FFF";
        // Append a space before the tag
        tagInputs.value += ' ';
        // Append the tag to the input field
        tagInputs.appendChild(ftext);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type ="text" class="Form-control" id="tags" onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event)" >
```

Comment: This code seems almost fixed but the span is created inside the input element. Should be after I assume. Also the `text` variable is never used.

Comment: The code on PC doesn't have the typo.

Comment: Getting an error that evt is not defined for the file where I did handleKeyUp(evt)

Comment: @VibrantWaves it should be `onkeyup="handleKeyUp(event)`

Comment: You forgot to mention that I need to move the definition of tagInputs into the function but you did it in the code, thanks.

Comment: does not work https://imgur.com/a/XO0DGv2